# How can I form heat sinks from waste aluminum?

Tags: recycling, diy, metal

I am designing a [thermo-electric generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator) system that would generate electricity from the heat of my wood stove.  The active components are bismuth telluride TEG cells that use the [Seebeck effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect) in reverse to convert a temperature difference into an electrical voltage.

The surface of the flat cell facing away from the wood stove needs to be cooled by a heat sink and fan so the semiconductor is not damaged.

I would like to fashion an aluminum heat sink out of waste aluminum  (foils, baking sheets, trays, etc).

Update: What I had in mind was a metal brake and bending system to fashion the fins and then bonding the fins to a flat piece of aluminum with a layer of heat sink compound adhesive.  Since the waste aluminum is thin and easily malleable, this should be trivial.  Melting it down and pouring into a mold in a vacuum would not be worth it.

Comment: Given that you can get extruded aluminium computer heat sinks from eBay for as low as $1.76 with free international shipping, I'm not sure why you would want to DIY one.  Nonetheless, if you want to spend more than $1.76 in fuel/energy, you could use propane/electricity to melt down a whole pile of random aluminium scraps and pour it into a sand cast.  A flat base plate with an array of rods sticking out of it (made using straws or knitting needles) would probably give you the conductivity and surface area you need.

Comment: You need a low O2 (ideally no O2) environment to melt aluminum.  If you heat aluminum in an O2 environment you'll just get aluminum oxide.  A propane torch definitely will not work.

Comment: lol... You might want to tell that to the tens/hundreds of thousands of people that smelt and sand cast aluminium for small projects every week.  ;)  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sand+cast+aluminium+propane

Answer (score 2):

Forget the foil.  Even if you laminate it, you'll never eliminate tiny air gaps, which will make it into a fairly effective insulator.

I've seen (copper) heatsinks made from thin precision-cut fins, soldered to a thicker spreader plate.  Solder is better than thermal epoxy, but doesn't work on aluminium.  This was necessary for a specific purpose, but not as effective as a similar-sized extruded aluminium heatsink despite the higher thermal conductivity of copper.

If you want to use recycled heatsinks, I suggest you use recycled heatsinks: Old computer heatsinks are effective (I had a collection from Pentium 2s that were very useful; they were huge as the only fan in those systems was a pathetic one in the PSU, with a duct pulling from the CPU heatsink.

Comment: Would brazing the copper be better than soldering since we are working with higher temperatures?

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty. Quite possibly. We didn't have the facilities to try, also soldering with paste in an oven is much quicker. I know in bike manufacturer aluminium is usually welded. It's not the easiest metal to weld but the strength you need is much less.